# JavaScript callback parameters?

Tags: javascript, dom, callback

Editing for obvious reasons.

As you can see, I have no idea what to pass in for the *cb* parameter in the tasker.login function. I've looked up how Callbacks work, but it does not make sense to me in this context how to use it. Any tips/advice would be helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Logging in won't be instant, so any code that you want to execute once the login has completed should be a function passed as the `cb` argument. Perhaps you want to remove a loader image that you placed on when you started logging in, or something similar.

Comment: Okay thanks for the info. Here is a note about the login(user. passwd, cb) function: "This function accepts the username and password of a user. After execution, the callback function is executed. The callback function is a function of two inputs: a user object and an error string."

Could you explain this?

Comment: So your function that you pass to `cb` will need to accept two argument, the first one will be an object that you can minipulate - it will have methods like `.logOut()` and `.changeProfilePicture()` ect. The second argument will be a string that contains an error message like `Password incorrect`

Comment: Ahh okay..I think I see what you're saying. Thanks for clarifying this to me! @Max

Comment: but what from arguments my *login(event)* method do I pass into my callback function I create?

Comment: I don't quite understand. You don't pass any arguments to the callback, `tasker.login` does that for you.

Comment: oh ok, I thought we had to. That makes more sense.

Comment: the function should probably be anonymous (a lambda) - try removing the "loginCallback" and place it as the cb argument.